# Rails: conflict error overwrite /home/username/blog/.gitignore?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm desperately trying to run a server and keep getting this mistake: `conflict  .gitignore`

The output is:

```
rails new blog
exist
identical  README.md
identical  Rakefile
identical  .ruby-version
identical  config.ru
conflict  .gitignore

Overwrite /home/jules/blog/.gitignore? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdhm]
```

What should I do? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. I'm an absolute beginner.

Answer (score 0):

When you run command `$rails new` it tries to create new rails application for you. But inside that folder that you are running this command file `.gitignore` already exists.

So, all that you need is to decide do you want to use your `.gitignore` file that already exists in current folder or to overwrite it with default one.

I think you made some mistake and just to make things simplier, try to run your command `rails new blog` in some separate empty folder.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you run `rails new blog` instead of `rails s`/`rails server`.
Since it already has all the files of a rails application called "blog", it's asking if it should overwrite the existing files with the new files it is creating because you ran `rails new blog`.